# nth-Child CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have nine sets of color schemes that I want to apply to a sequence of divs. Using `:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2)...` works for the first nine, but I'd like the sequence to then repeat after that, and I can't wrap my head around the (3n+2) notation... I think I get it, but I can't seem to coax it into doing what I want.

Is this possible, or should I just apply a class to each div as I write them out?

Comment: If you want backwards compatibility, you ought to use classes, as `nth-child` isn't supported in Internet Exploder.

Comment: You can find a slightly dated CSS3 compatibility matrix at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html.  If you look up the 'nth-child' selector you'll notice that support is sketchy in the IE realm. If you really want/need to use those selectors and don't mind using javascript in your application you can use jQuery to implement those selectors in IE<9.

Comment: This is for a fun / hobby project so I'm not too concerned with browser backwards-compatibility, but more with taking the opportunity to learn how some of the new CSS3 features work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean you need to apply different rules to every nine consecutive elements, you have to use these nine selectors:

```
:nth-child(9n+1)
:nth-child(9n+2)
:nth-child(9n+3)
:nth-child(9n+4)
:nth-child(9n+5)
:nth-child(9n+6)
:nth-child(9n+7)
:nth-child(9n+8)
:nth-child(9n+9) /* Or :nth-child(9n) */
```

Comment: Shouldn't this start with :nth-child(9n+1) since CSS selectors begin at index 1?

Comment: @Joe Landsman You're right, doing it this way resulted in the `:nth-child(9n)` not being applied until the 10th element, rather than the first.

Answer (score 6):

First a few tidbits:

- nth-child uses `1`-based indices for matching (i.e. `nth-child(1)` is the first child, not the second)
- `n` in the `An + B` notation is the iterator value
- `n` starts at `0` and counts up
- `An + B` will be a matched index (I'll call it `i`)

[read the spec for more info](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

If you have a set of elements you want to match, you ought to write them out:

Example:

```
1st, 10th, 19th, 28th...
```

In this case you want to match `n` to specific indices

```
n | i
======
0 |  1
1 | 10
2 | 19
3 | 28
4 | 37
etc...
```

If we solve for `An + B = i` using `n = 0`, `i = 1` we can get the value of B:

```
A(0) + B = 1
B = 1
```

We can then use this value in a second substitution using `n = 1`, `i = 10`:

```
A(1) + 1 = 10;
A = 9;
```

So we now have `9n + 1` for a selector to match `1,10,19,28,etc`

You can rinse and repeat for each different selection, but pretty soon you ought to realize that the repetition happens every `A` elements, and the offset is `B` elements.

<sub>The `nth-child` selector is a great real-world example of where high-school algebra is **actually useful**</sub>

Comment: Very thorough, thanks! If the examples I read before posting this question had simply said `The repetition happens every A elements, and the offset is B elements`, I would have understood it right away.

Comment: It is easy to understand, thank you.