# CSS - How to select nth-child of form element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to re-design the registration form of my WP website. I also add some exta fields. I increase the width of `<form>` container and set `<input>` field's flow to left. But I want to set flow of phone field (which is third child of `<form>` element) to none i.e. `float: none;`. I try to do this: `form:nth-child(3) {float: none;}` but it seen to be not working. It selects form rather then 3rd field of form. What is wrong?

[Here](http://latestpknews.tk/wp-login.php?action=register) is registration page of my site. Please help.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using the input's id `#user_phone`?

Comment: duplicate of this question and about 200 other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206573/nth-child-css-selectors

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Actually `<input>` wrap in `<p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the descendant combinator (the space):

```
form :nth-child(3) {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Without the space, you're selecting the `form`-element *if* it's the third-child of its parent, with the space you're selecting the third-child elements of the `form`. To get only those elements that are *direct* descendants:

```
form > :nth-child(3) {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Reference:

- [CSS Selectors, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Answer (score 3):

```
form > p:nth-child(3){
  float: none;   
}
```

for IE 7:

```
form > p + p + p{
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The x:anything selector relates to the x, so your selector selects the FORM, which is the 3rd child in its parent.

what you want to do is simply `form input:nth-child(3) {float: none;}`

If you have other children in the form like `<p>` etc., better use `form input:nth-of-type(3) {float: none;}`

PS: you have to watch out, if you are using `<select>` or `<textarea>` too, which aren't found in this varariant.