# HTML list with different images as bullets

Tags: html, list

I know it is possible to set an image instead of the HTML default bullets:

```
list-style-image: url(...);
```

But I havent't found a way how I can set different images in one and the same list. e.G.: Instead of the first bullet, img_1 is shown, instead of the next 5 bullets img_2 is displayed ... .

Comment: `first-child`, `nth-child` - http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206573/nth-child-css-selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML-

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

CSS(doesn't work on IE 7,8)-

```
ul li:nth-child(1){
list-style-image:url('image1.png');
}
ul li:nth-child(2){
list-style-image:url('image2.png');
}
ul li:nth-child(3){
list-style-image:url('image3.png');
}
```

CSS for all Browser including IE 7,8

```
ul li:first-child{
list-style-image:url('image1.png');
}
ul li:first-child + li{
list-style-image:url('image2.png');
}
ul li:first-child + li + li{
list-style-image:url('image3.png');
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li{
list-style-image:url('image4.png');
}
```

Comment: This one works quite well for me since I have a different image for every bullet. Furthermore, for me it seems to be the "cleanest" variant. If I would've to set one image for a range of bullets,I'd rather go for the class version.

Comment: FYI: the nth-child selector will not work in IE8, so think about the browser support before using the nth-child selector

Answer (score 3):

Just add a different class in the LI element

```
<ul class="navlist">
    <li class="img_1">element1</li>
    <li class="img_2">element2</li>
</ul>
<style>
.navlist li.img_1
{
padding-left: 10px;
background-image: url(images/image1.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 .5em;
}
.navlist li.img_2
{
padding-left: 10px;
background-image: url(images/image2.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 .5em;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use  `nth-child` Property

CSS

```
li:nth-child(1){list-style-image:url(image)}
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/5VB2u/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with classes

```
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="second"></li>
...

li.first {
  ⋮ declarations
}

li.second {
  ⋮ declarations
}
...
```

or the [nth-child selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

```
li:nth-child(1) {
  ⋮ declarations
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  ⋮ declarations
}
...
```

Comment: FYI: the nth-child selector will not work in IE8, so think about the browser support before using the nth-child selector

Answer (score 1):

you have to/can use classes in your list items:

```
<ul>
  <li class="bar>
   <a href="#" title="foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li class="foo>
   <a href="#" title="bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS for images as bullets for `<li>`

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
 padding-left: 25px; /*adjust to your needs*/
}
li.bar {
  background: url(img_2.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
li.foo {
  background: url(img_1.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

CSS for images as bullets for `<a>`

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li a {
 padding-left: 25px; /*adjust to your needs*/
 display: block;
}
li.bar a {
  background: url(img_2.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
li.foo a {
  background: url(img_1.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

Comment: I asked for a bullet-image. Is it really the same when I use the `background` css-attribute?

Comment: yes, its the same, if you want full control over the images in one list as bullet replacements

Comment: full control means, I can also set those images as links?

Comment: if you add them as background image to your <a> instead of the <li>? yes