# Change color of multiple elements with same class with CSS (different count of DOM elements in row)

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change the color of some badges in an list.

```
<div id="tree">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item node-tree" ><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span><a href="#" style="color:inherit;">Test</a><span class="badge">123</span><span class="badge">123</span><span class="badge">3223</span><span class="badge">23</span><span class="badge">323</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item node-tree"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span><a href="#" style="color:inherit;">Test 1</a><span class="badge">321</span><span class="badge">123</span><span class="badge">3223</span><span class="badge">23</span><span class="badge">323</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It still works with jQuery, for example with:

```
 $("#tree .list-group-item").each(function(){

            $(this).find('.badge:eq(4)').css('background-color','#bf5329');
            $(this).find('.badge:eq(4)').css('color','#fff');

            $(this).find('.badge:eq(3)').css('background-color','#2ab27b');
            $(this).find('.badge:eq(3)').css('color','#fff');

            $(this).find('.badge:eq(2)').css('background-color','#bf5329');
            $(this).find('.badge:eq(2)').css('color','#fff');

            $(this).find('.badge:eq(1)').css('background-color','#2ab27b');
            $(this).find('.badge:eq(1)').css('color','#fff');

            $(this).find('.badge:eq(0)').css('background-color','#3B4752');
            $(this).find('.badge:eq(0)').css('color','#fff');
        });
```

But my Problem is, when ill change the tree, i need to call the method again (and again..) - so i would prefer to create the same with CSS only, but when ill try with:

```
#tree .list-group-item .badge:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #bf5329;   
}
```

Its not setting EVERY .list-group-item, only the first one (and there are about 100 "rows".

Any ideas?

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30190/

Update with CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30192/

Thanks for your answers - but ill still have a problem if there are some more

```
 <span>
```

inside my

```
 .list-group-item
```

In this case its a treeview, and there are some "indent" classes. Check out here:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30196/

Any more ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `first-child` and not `nth-child` ?

Comment: only as example - its not working with first-child and nth-child. It only changes the color of the first element in the whole list, not in every row.

Comment: Would you please update your question and include your attempt at `nth-child` ?

Comment: already did - added new version of fiddle too (now i am unable to change any color)

Comment: Of course - but when ill use with the .list-group-item selector, the nth-child(1) should be the first element in EVERY .list-group-item Element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nth-Child CSS Selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206573/nth-child-css-selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `$('.badge').eq(0)` in CSS here will be `.badge:nth-child(4)` since the first `.badge` is the 4th child of it's parent. Then you can increment that by 1 to target the rest of them.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

span.badge {
  color: #fff;
}
span.badge:nth-child(4) {
  background: #3B4752;
}
span.badge:nth-child(5) {
  background: #2ab27b;
}
span.badge:nth-child(6) {
  background: #bf5329;
}
span.badge:nth-child(7) {
  background: #2ab27b;
}
span.badge:nth-child(8) {
  background: #bf5329;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="tree">
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="0" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span><a href="#" style="color:inherit;">Test</a><span class="badge">123</span><span class="badge">123</span><span class="badge">3223</span><span class="badge">23</span><span class="badge">323</span></li>
<li class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="0" style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span><a href="#" style="color:inherit;">Test 1</a><span class="badge">321</span><span class="badge">123</span><span class="badge">3223</span><span class="badge">23</span><span class="badge">323</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but can u please explain why u use 4,5,6,7,8 element?

Comment: @derdida  `nth-child(1)` doesn't target the first instance of an element, it targets the selector if it's the first child of an element.

Comment: Ah thanks for your answer! Gimme one second please ill try it out with my list of about 100 rows.

Comment: So my problem now is when ill use and additional class (in this case "indent, to make an tree" - i am unable to use css in this case (because there are additional <span></span> inside my <li> - is it possible to solve this with CSS only? Check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30195/

Comment: @derdida give the little icons you want to color a consistent parent so that `:nth-child()` will be the same between the rows. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30197/

Comment: I just want to color the existing badges - this is an existing treeview plugin (otherwise i need to extend that in the plugin) - can i explain please what have you changed in the html? i cant find it ;) - and thanks for your help!

Comment: @derdida Just wrap the badges in `<span class="pull-right">...</span>` then make the CSS change I made which references different indexes of `:nth-child()`

Comment: Thanks again - i will extend the plugin with this tiny wrapper!

Answer (score 1):

Each of your `.list-group-item` consists of the following elements:

```
<span class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
<span class="icon node-icon"></span>
<a href="#" style="color:inherit;">Test</a>
<span class="badge">123</span>
<span class="badge">123</span>
<span class="badge">3223</span>
<span class="badge">23</span>
<span class="badge">323</span>
```

Then e.g. `.list-group-item .badge:nth-of-child(1)` will select each child of `list-group-item` that

- has the class `.badge` AND
- is the first child of its parent.

However, the first child of `list-group-item` is `<span class="icon /* ... */"></span>`, so the selector won't match. You can either go with what Michael Coker describes in his answer (select the 4th child and so on) or use e.g. `<i>` tags for the icons, so you can make use of the [`nth-of-type`-selector](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type):

```
span:nth-of-type(1) { /* ... */ }
```

What would fit best for your example would be some *nth-of-class*-selector, which unfortunately [does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931957/3162554). It would allow a maximum of flexibility with the number of elements (which isn't given in Michael's answer) and a maximum of flexibility with using `<span>`s also for other childs of `.list-group-item`, that are not badges (which isn't given in my answer).

Comment: So it is unable to do something (as shown in my latest fiddle) with pure css?

Comment: It is possible by changing the markup, so that the badges have a parent that does not contain childs other than badges. See Michael's latest comment ^^

Comment: Thanks Marvin for your help! I will extend the plugin with this tiny code.